# isSSL false even though I've set tls to True when sending mail

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to use an external smtp server from my springboot-application (scaffolded by JHipster). I have set the folling in my applocation.yml, and it picks up everything except the SSH settings.

```
host: send.one.com
    port: 465
    username: user@name 
    password: password
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    auth: true
    from: user@name
```

When i run the app I can see the following in my log

```
[DEBUG] com.sun.mail.smtp - useEhlo true, useAuth true
[DEBUG] com.sun.mail.smtp - trying to connect to host "send.one.com", port 465, isSSL false
[DEBUG] com.sun.mail.smtp - EOF: [EOF]
[DEBUG] com.sun.mail.smtp - could not connect to host "send.one.com", port: 465, response: -1
```

it seems the application is trying to connect without ssl, and it won't connect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you ping to 'send.one.com' on port 465?

Comment: Yes, that works: `$ telnet send.one.com 465
Trying 91.198.169.21...
Connected to csmtp-cluster.one.com.
Escape character is '^]'.`

Answer (score 0):

You try to send over TLS. In general the standard port used by TLS is 587 and not 465 which is used for SSL. Try whether it works with that port?